# Understanding 「フレーズ句切りが行なわれた文に対して，アクセント変形を考慮した上で文としてのピッチパターンを表示します。」

Tags: translation

I'm trying to parse the first sentence of [OJAD](https://www.gavo.t.u-tokyo.ac.jp/ojad/phrasing/index)'s README:

> **フレーズ句切りが行なわれた文に対して，アクセント変形を考慮した上で文としてのピッチパターンを表示します。**「，、．。,.？！?!：:」「／/」及び改行がフレーズの句切りとなります。これはユーザが指定します。また「。．.？！?!」と改行が文の句切りとなります。文の句切れは必ずフレーズの句切れとなります。疑問文にも対応しています。OJAD教科書版と異なり，形態素解析，アクセント句境界推定，アクセント核推定などの技術を用いているため，精度は100%ではありませんが，日本語の学習にお役立て下さい。

**Questions/Attempt:**

1. Is a 「フレーズ句切り」 a "punctuated phrase"?

   - What's the difference between 句切り and 句切れ? Does 句切り mean "punctuation" while 句切れ means "phrase" (synonym of フレーズ)?
2. フレーズ句切りが行なわれた: "The ('punctuated') phrase that was input"?
3. フレーズ句切りが行なわれた**文に対して**: "Concerning the sentence (compromised of a punctuated phrase)"?
4. アクセント変形を考慮した上で: "After accent changes are considered"?
5. 文として: "taken as a sentence"?
6. 文としてのピッチパターン: "The thing's (taken as a sentence) pitch pattern"?

   - Why does is this constructed this way? Why not just say 「文のピッチパターン」 instead?
7. アクセント変形を考慮した上で文としてのピッチパターンを表示します: "Signifies the taken-as-a-sentence thing's pitch pattern"

**Overall:**

> "Concerning the sentence (compromised of a punctuated phrase): after the accent changes are considered, signifies the taken-as-a-sentence thing's pitch pattern".

This comes off as near gibberish to me, so I am clearly not understanding how to parse this sentence correctly :) Can anyone provide insights on where I've gone wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- 句切り is from 句切る (transitive) and 句切れ is from 句切れる (intransitive). フレーズ句切り refers to someone's (intentional) action of delimiting phrases. フレーズの句切れ might be used to refer to unintentional pauses between phrases, etc.
- 対して is just "against ～" or "for ～".
- 文として is "as a sentence".

Literally:

> フレーズ句切りが行なわれた文に対して、
> for sentences where phrase-delimiting has been performed,
>
> アクセント変形を考慮した上で
> (after) taking accent changes into consideration,
>
> 文としてのピッチパターンを表示します。
> (the system) displays the pitch pattern as a sentence (as opposed to the pitch pattern as an individual word).

Overall:

> For a sentence that has been (manually) divided into phrases, (this system) displays its pitch pattern within a sentence, taking accent changes into account.

In other words, unlike conventional accent textbooks that only include the pitch accent when words are pronounced in isolation, this system takes into account various other factors (such as those [involving suffixes](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/80063/5010)), and displays the pitch accent as they would actually be spoken within a sentence.

Comment: Do you know why it's 文としての as opposed to just 文として? Is the の acting possessively?

Comment: @George Yes kind of. 文として works adverbially (modifies a verb), and 文としての works adjectivally (modifies a noun). 文として表示する means "to present (something) as a sentence", but this is different from the intended meaning. 文としてのピッチアクセント is "pitch accent as used in a sentence".

Comment: naruto: Your answers make everything in Japanese look so easy :)

Comment: At a later point in the OJAD passage it reads「文の**句切れ**は必ずフレーズの**句切れ** となります」. This auto-translates to "the sentence endpoints will always become the endpoints of phrases". Do you know why 句切れ is being used here instead of 句切り to mean "endpoint"? Usage of the intransitive 句切れ seems to suggest the endpoint is unintentional, no? But in this context, sentence endpoints are *purposely_ demarcated by punctuation marks or linebreaks, so wouldn't 句切り be more appropriate?

Comment: @George 文の句切れ, or sentence boundaries, are more obvious than phrase boundaries even when you speak naturally without thinking about grammar, so I think the author used 句切れ almost unconsciously here. Prescriptively speaking, terms should be used consistently in a short text like this.